# Call a python script and get its return value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, variables, return

what I'm triying to achieve is to get the number of IP's connected to my server and:

```
if connected IP's < 2 --> Load index.html
otherwise             --> Load otherpage.html
```

With Python I get the number of IP's connected (works fine) but I need to pass that value to javascript in order to load one html or the other. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Call your Python script from an Ajax call in the web page.  Return the result from Python as JSON and then your ajax call can parse the JSON into javascript to have the result.

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer. Could you post some kind of documentation to follow in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Aldridge1991 One must do some work himself. Try to use search engines for how to "achieve your goal"... (I don't mean to be rude)..

Answer (score 0):

To interact with Python from JavaScript you need a

- Some sort of web server
- Some soft of web framework

Your question does not specify if you know anything about this components. Is this first website project you are doing in Python?

I suggest you study Python web framework alternatives and complete their tutorials before proceeding. Few listed below.

- http://flask.pocoo.org/
- http://www.pylonsproject.org/
- https://www.djangoproject.com/

Flask is "micro-framework", must suitable for a tiny task like this.

You can do a HTTP web server also in a pure Python (no framework) but that is not recommended for a novice, as it gets complex fast.

Comment: I'm using Apache2 (as it's running on a Raspberry Pi). I'm quite new in this field but I learn fast. Instead of those frameworks I'm using CGI.